# Variable 'Button' never assigned (Java using android studio)

Tags: java, button, unassigned-variable

First: Apologies if this question has been asked several times already. I just couldn't find a fix.

Compiler in android studio returns "1 error":

```
Button button_go2activity findViewById(R.id.button_go2activity);

Error code: variable 'button_go2activity' never assigned
```

This is confusing to me. I also have another button, which I assigned the same (and which works fine).  I also tried to add the variable 'button' in the strings.xml (although it works with the other button without that declaration).

Please see the code attached.
Many thanks for your help.

Best,
Constantin

```
package paperpad.app;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //private Button button;              //button because otherwise not declared???
    @Override


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button_openHelp = findViewById(R.id.button_openHelp);    //connect button "open help" to xml
        button_openHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     //find button
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                  //activity when button "open help" is clicked
                Intent openHelp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com"));      //link to paperPad youtube channel
                startActivity(openHelp);
            }
        });


        Button button_go2activity findViewById(R.id.button_go2activity);
        button_go2activity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivity_loadPicture();                 //activity defined below
            }
        });
    }
    public void openActivity_loadPicture() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, loadpicture.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are missing the `=` assignment operator. The line that defines `button_go2activity` should look like:

```
Button button_go2activity = findViewById(R.id.button_go2activity);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint. I spend 2 hours yesterday, trying to find what's wrong :/. Wish you a great day.